# Denormalization of large text?

Tags: mysql, memcached, nosql, denormalization

If I have large articles that need to be stored in a database, each associated with many tables would a NoSQL option help? Should I copy the 1000 char articles over multiple "buckets", duplicating them each time they are related to a bucket or should I use a normalized MySQL DB with lots of Memcache?

Comment: i don't think that normalization is an issue here. You have article row in table where the text is. if design is correct no copying is needed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When storing data normalising it is essential, and will save you time further down the line 99% of the time, even if you think you are saving time at the time.  Always normalise!

Also you have terminologoy problem, de-normilisation refers to taking normalised data and breaking it down and restoring it as repeated data.

Comment: Agree.  The only exception to normalization is if you have HUGE tables that you need to query against a lot (and hence a lot of joins).  Then, you can gain quite a bit by denormalization.  But personally I always keep a fully normalized copy along side a denormalized copy.  Some querieis are FAR better with a normalized set, and others are better with a denormalized set.  Maintaining both increases your flexibility (At the price of disk space and complexity)...